# CSS Transition on max-height doesn't ease when max-height increases from 0 (Pure CSS)

Tags: html, css

1. Could someone please tell me why the animation works properly when the max-height goes to 0 but not the other way round? When the max-height is set to 1000px, the list snaps open instead of easing in. I am trying to achieve this animation using only CSS.
2. Also, is there a better way to do this other than using max-height. I am setting the max-height to 1000px. I want it to expand automatically to the height it requires without me choosing a random value.

Thanks for your help!

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
}

.accordion .tab {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.accordion .tab input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.accordion .tab input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.accordion .tab input[type="checkbox"] ~ ul {
  max-height: 1000px;
  transition: max-height .5s ease;
}
.accordion .tab input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .5s ease;
}
.accordion .tab ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.accordion .tab ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tab1">
    <label for="tab1">Cars</label>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="checkbox" id="tab2">
    <label for="tab2">Trucks</label><ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you `transition` to `max-height: 1000px;`, the transition assumes the height of the element is going to be 1000px, so the transition has to cover 1000px in `.5s`. When you transition back to 0, it knows the actual height already, so it it only has to transition that height (say 300px) back to 0px in `.5s` which would be more than twice as slow.
2. You can slow it down by specifying a smaller max-height. As for the method being used, you're using the only css solution if you need it to transition dynamic heights.  You may consider using a JS/Jquery solution to calculate the height and then transition that.